# Slideshow lacks Javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, plugins, slideshow

I found this beautiful website (http://soworldwide.org/) and want to create a similar slideshow. After I've spend a lot of time to make it work, I still can't figure it out.

Right now it's looking like this:

http://bit.ly/1bktxcx

Wait undtil the last picture and then you can see how the slideshow refreshes. Can someone help me, so I get the same animation like theirs?

I'm using the same Jquery Plugin by the way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Didn't get enough help last time you posted this?

Comment: People didn't respond. This time I linked my slideshow, so people could see what I was talking about. If no one helps me this time I will stop posting. Promise.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the top of the list-begin image to zero at the same time that you're starting the animation for the list-end image. Because the zIndex of the list-begin image is 3, you're causing the list-begin image to hide the animation of the list-end image. I recommend dynamically updating the zIndex for each image when you do the animation. For slides that are hidden (by setting the top to a negative value, as you're doing), you can ignore the zIndex. But before you set the top to zero for your `next` image, set the zIndex for `curr` to 1 and the zIndex for `next` to 0.

***Edit:*** I figured this out using the Chrome JS debugger and liberal use of `console.log()`. Maybe you did all the right things and still couldn't find the problem, and just needed a second set of eyes. But if you didn't do all the right things, remember: the debugger is a powerful tool.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But I'm a little confused by how you mean I should fix it. Can you simplify somehow? I do not have so much experience with coding, sorry.

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought you had written the plugin yourself. I recommend googling 'Cycle Lite Plugin' or maybe going to a more general help forum to ask for help with it. There is a jQuery forum for that plugin [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-cycle-lite-plugin). Good luck!